# Rewrite URL relative to current directory

Tags: .htaccess

I have a directory: /test, in that directory I have a file called World.txt. And a .htaccess file that's in the /test directory.

When the user goes to http://example.com/test/Hello.txt they should be redirected to http://example.com/test/World.txt

So I put this in the .htaccess file:

RewriteRule Hello.txt World.txt

This doesn't work, I think it is doing http://example.com/test/Hello.txt -> http://example.com/World.txt

As if I try:

RewriteRule Hello.txt /test/World.txt

It works, however this means if I rename the test directory, I have to remember to change the rewrite rule.

Is there a flag or something that makes the redirect path relative to the current directory?

Answer (score 1):

You can probably have a `RewriteBase` line at top:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test/

RewriteRule ^Hello\.txt$ World.txt [NC,L]
```

You can have any number of rules in this .htaccess without repeating `/test/` in every rule.

**EDIT:** On another note for me this worked even without `RewriteBase` line:

```
RewriteRule ^Hello\.txt$ ./World.txt [NC,L]
```